# Does the analytics works on the studio Liberty Profile?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

WL 6.0.0.1

I was testing analytics and I configured everything in the worklight studio liberty profile. Everything seems to be correct as I saw the analytics traces in the device console and also the analytics tab but there was no data at all in the widgets.

I configured a new Liberty profile using the WL Server Enterprise Edition binaries and in this other profile I could see all the information in the analytics widgets.

Does analytics works in the studio liberty profile server or I was doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the analytics tab empty, or are you seeing empty charts in the analytics tab?

Comment: empty charts in the analytics tab.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen just this post, but I'm not sure if saying that I'm using the studio is the same that say I'm using developer edition.

[Worklight v6 iwap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278110/worklight-v6-iwap/19792958#19792958)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Is studio the same as as saying you're using the developer edition? Not necessarily; Worklight Studio is a component in both the paid editions (Enterprise Edition and Consumer Edition) and the free edition ([Developer Edition](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/) - available for evaluation purposes). Studio includes a built-in Liberty Profile for development.

To answer your question: Does analytics work in the studio liberty profile server? Analytics was only intended to work with one of the paid editions for test/production mode, so it was not enabled for running on Liberty within Studio. However, you can get it to work within the Worklight 6.0 Studio Liberty server by setting wl.analytics.debug=true flag in the worklight properties to try it out.